# Change device settings in Xcode after multiple releases

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have an iOS application in App Store only for iPhone and iPod devices. In deployment info > devices is set to iPhone.

Now I'm trying to program this app also for iPad and I'll like to know if Apple will reject my application in next release when I change iPhone to Universal in deployment info > devices.

Comment: No, they don't reject your app for that ;)

Comment: @carro They'll test it against both iPhone and iPad and will allow or reject it based on how it conforms to all the device-specific requirements.